# Core Data Migration Multiple Passes?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I am implementing a core data data version changes for one of my ipad applications. Apparently some user of my app has more than 1GB large database. As a result doing data migration using "light weight" will blow up the memory. Therefore, I was trying to do a customized data migration with multiple passes(Suggested by Apple). However, I am not sure how would I divide one mapping model into several small mapping models(ideally one per each entity), since on the generated mapping model entity mappings are all related.

I won't be able to post a image because of I am new to stack overflow

Inside of the mapping models I added two more mappings. For one DataMedia, I need to create two ASData to store the media binary data in a separate table. The large data is store initially in "DataMedia" table(in a worst case that table is almost 800MB large).

So here is my question:
1. What is the best way to do this migration with out blowing out the memory?
2. Is multiple passes migration a solution? if so how do I divided the entity mappings with relationships to each-other into separate mapping models? Does that mean that I need to manually implement the "Relationship Mapping"?

Comment: Have you confirmed that lightweight migration will fail with large databases? I've done migrations with over 500MB databases and did it without crashing due to memory.

Comment: Yes. I tried light weight migration using Instruments. The highest memory for one particular migration is 400MB, however, one my device it throws memory warning at 270MB. Have you monitored the memory usage for your light weighted migration case? what is the maximum memory usage?

Comment: I've never monitored specifically for lightweight migration. Never had an issue about it (not even a memory warning), so I never particularly paid attention to it. While on development, I look closely to all memory warnings. Never had one for lightweight migration. Could you expand a little more on the type of changes you are making, and the type of data on your database?

Comment: ok, basically I have a table(MEDIA) contains two huge columns that contains binaries(mostly image data). I have to normalize this (MEDIA) table and move the binary into DATA table(a new table that I have to create in a new version of my datamodel). So along with the migration I use custom migration policy inside of MediaToMedia mapping to create two new DATA records in the destinationContext. The memory got explode when the system tries to migrate MEDIA objects...